# Why can't I run after installing anaconda?

Tags: anaconda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda on the official website and installed it according to the online tutorial. But when I clicked and ran Anaconda Navigator, the program disappeared after the black box popped up, and then there was no response.

1. I tried to "conda info --envs", then it give "base * C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"
2. I tried to "conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator", then it give "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/current_repodata.json
   Elapsed"
3. my user env variable is "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\;C:\Program Files\Python37\"

I expect Anaconda can be run and the reason why it doesn't work, though it is download by official website.

Comment: the system windows 10,  64

Comment: I found a post that successfully solved my problem. But I still can't understand why this problem occurs.  https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41761293/article/details/86988511

Comment: This problem should be caused by the incomplete python downloaded from the anaconda official website. I really can't understand why it's a problem with ssl. Is it because I used vpn?

Answer (score 0):

download complete anaconda package
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section
and the navigator will be installed automatically